# jboss wildfly datasource deployment via IntelliJ

Tags: deployment, intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly-8

I am currently setting up a Java EE project with IntelliJ. For local testing I am using a local Jboss wildfly where I deploy the application via artifacts and a run configuration defined in Idea.

I would like to use the "deployable datasource approach" where the jdbc driver and the corresponding mysql-ds.xml descriptor file is deployed manually to jboss.

In the deployment dialog of the run configuration I am able to choose the driver .jar file but IntelliJ doesn't show the mysql-ds.xml file.

Is there any way to deploy this additional descriptor file outside of an archive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildfly-maven-plugin [here](http://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/complex-example.html) is complete example how to add datasource

Answer (score 0):

you can also use external wildfly home specified at plugin level like [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/254169?_sscc=t)